# How to get variable labels of regression output in matrix

Tags: variables, label, naming-conventions, stata

In Stata, say that I have these data:

```
sysuse auto2, clear
gen name = substr(make, 1,3)
encode name, gen(name2)
```

I run this regression, which importantly uses `i.`:

```
reg price i.name2 trunk weight turn
```

The output takes the form of:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       name2 |
        Aud  |   4853.048   1254.083     3.87   0.000     2331.545    7374.551
        BMW  |   5742.124   1560.161     3.68   0.001     2605.211    8879.037
        Bui  |   1351.065    946.733     1.43   0.160    -552.4696    3254.599
        Cad  |   7740.865   1168.332     6.63   0.000     5391.776    10089.95
        Che  |   62.35577   946.1153     0.07   0.948    -1839.937    1964.648
....
```

I then go to the estimation results:

```
matrix list e(b)
```

which produces:

```
e(b)[1,27]
            1b.          2.          3.          4.          5.          6.          7.
         name2       name2       name2       name2       name2       name2       name2
y1           0   4853.0482   5742.1237   1351.0647   7740.8653   62.355771   2676.3971

             8.          9.         10.         11.         12.         13.         14.
         name2       name2       name2       name2       name2       name2       name2
y1    943.4266   1964.8242   1776.4058   2711.4324   6386.7936 
....
```

My question is how can I retrieve the variable labels from the `name2` variable after the regression is run? What I want is what is displayed in the initial output: `Aud`, `BMW`, `Bui`, etc. I do not want what is stored in the `e(b)` matrix: `1b. name2`, `2. name2`, `3. name2`, etc. Is there a way to get what I want stored in `e(b)` or is is stored elsewhere in other estimation results? Can `estout/esttab`? I would like to get the results stored in a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store e(b) in a matrix, get the names of your variable with the `levelsof` command and rename the column names.

```
sysuse auto2, clear
gen name = substr(make, 1,3)
encode name, gen(name2) 

reg price i.name2 trunk weight turn
mat A = e(b)

levelsof name, local(names)
local colnames "`names' trunk weight turn _cons"
matrix colnames A = `colnames'
matrix list A
```